# How to Center align the Navigation bar on this link?

Tags: responsive-design, alignment, center

http://medialoot.com/preview/css-only-navigation-menu/index.html

I'm learning how to make a website responsive and I came across this issue. 
You see the ul left aligned and I'm trying to make it center aligned.
It kinda looks simple but I couldn't solve it. Please help.

Comment: You could stick it in a div, remove the float:left from the `li`s, set the margin to 0 auto

Comment: Thanks for replying Evan but the solution you provided doesn't work. Can you check with it one more time?

Comment: Okay - tested, you'll need to remove the position absolute from the ul and set text-align on the div to center instead of setting the margins.

Comment: When position absolute is removed from the ul, hover functionality doesnt work. Did you recognize that, Evan?